# Shuffle multiple select menu options with one click button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Basically i have 8 option value. I want to randomly generate the value of each option with one click of the generate button. any suggestion? Thank you in advance
[the UI like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLoPr.png)

cshtml code :

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select name="" id="txtCupA" class="form-control">
                                <option value="SWEET">SWEET</option>
                                <option value="SOUR">SOUR</option>
                                <option value="SALTY">SALTY</option>
                                <option value="BITTER">BITTER</option>
                                <option value="UMAMI">UMAMI</option>
                                <option value="WATER">WATER</option>
                                <option value="WATER">WATER</option>
                                <option value="WATER">WATER</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Could you please share your relevant code snippet? So that it can be reproduced?

Comment: cshtml code added

Comment: Well, so while you would like to bind the value with `onclick` event you want to pick a random value from this `option list` right?  Just confirm I understand that correctly.

Comment: yes sir, when generate btn with onCLick clicked will pick random "each of string" value but every option value won't be the same value so the choices will be spread over each option

Comment: Does it mean you want shuffle dropdown value by button click? Means when you would click the button all value need to be shuffled randomly is it right?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Got your point, try the solution, it will help you to implement exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to randomly generate the value of each option with one click of the generate button. Any suggestion?

You could follow the steps below:

**Asp.net Core Views:**

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select id="txtCupA" class="form-control">
            <option value="SWEET">SWEET</option>
            <option value="SOUR">SOUR</option>
            <option value="SALTY">SALTY</option>
            <option value="BITTER">BITTER</option>
            <option value="UMAMI">UMAMI</option>
            <option value="WATER">WATER</option>
            <option value="WATER">WATER</option>
            <option value="WATER">WATER</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" id="shuffleDropDown" value="Suffle Value" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>
```

**Scripts:**

```
@section scripts {
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
 
  $(document).ready(function() {

    function funcArrayShuffle(array) {

        var currentIndex = array.length,
            temporaryValue, randomIndex;
        while (0 !== currentIndex) {
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex -= 1;
            temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
        }
        return array;
    }


    $("#shuffleDropDown").click(function() {

        //Getting the current dropdown List
        var options = $('#txtCupA option');
        var values = $.map(options, e => $(e).val())

        //Make It random
        var shuffleddItemList = funcArrayShuffle(values);

        //Made the older drowdownList empty
        var dropdown = $('#txtCupA');
        dropdown.empty();

        //Loop through the Shaffle array item and made the New Random Dropdown List
        $.each(shuffleddItemList, function(index, item) {
            console.log(index, item);
            dropdown.append(
                $('<option>', {
                    value: item,
                    text: item
                }, '</option>'))
        });
    });


});


</script>
        }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Algorithm:**

1. First Getting the current Dropdownlist
2. Making the current dropdown item shuffled
3. Removing current dowpdown item from existing node
4. Populating the new dropdown value with random item

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but how if i have 8 dropdown list when clicked only 1 button the shuffle values will pick random value , but in every dropdown value won't be the same and the choices of value will be spread over each dropdown?
like the example picture attached above

Comment: `"but how if i have 8 dropdown list when clicked only 1 button the shuffle values will pick random value"` could you please post new question with your new concern. Share your current issue and expectation there along with related code snippet so that it can be resolved there.

Comment: sure, new question post here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72371461/shuffle-multiple-option-value-with-one-click-generate-button-2